# IIS Windows Authentication block disabled users?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

I had been searching for this question without an answer:
Does anyone know if a user that has been blocked can access a site with windows authentication?
(the project wrote in MVC - Intranet project with windows authentication)

Comment: If a windows account is disabled it will not authenticate.

Comment: if the user blocked after he already logged into windows, will he be able to get access to the page?

Comment: If he has already logged into your site, maybe, but maybe not.. try it .. this is the quickest way to test anything - see for yourself

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the help!